# Extending Django Oauth2 Application Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I was trying to Extend Oauth2 Application Model using this [link](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced_topics.html#extending-the-application-model.).

But some problem comming while i am migrating -

> ValueError: The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was
>   declared with a lazy reference to
>   'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but app 'oauth2' isn't
>   installed. The field oauth2_provider.Grant.application was declared
>   with a lazy reference to 'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but
>   app 'oauth2' isn't installed. The field
>   oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application was declared with a lazy
>   reference to 'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but app 'oauth2'
>   isn't installed.

I have add oauth2 in installed_apps still it is giving error

Settings.py

```
installed_apps = [
   'apps.oauth2',
]

OAUTH2_PROVIDER_APPLICATION_MODEL='oauth2.CompanyFieldAddedApplication'
```

My Project Structure

```
├── apollo_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py.ren
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
│   ├── oauth2
│   │   ├── admin.py
│   │   ├── apps.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── migrations
│   │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
│   │   │   ├── 0002_auto_20190215_1402.py
│   │   │   └── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
│   │   ├── urls.py
│   │   └── views.py
```

project_folder > apps > oauth2 > models.py

```
from django.db import models
from oauth2_provider.models import AbstractApplication
from apps.company.models import Company

class CompanyFieldAddedApplication(AbstractApplication):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 163, in handle
    pre_migrate_apps = pre_migrate_state.apps
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 37, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 210, in apps
    return StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models)
  File "/home/codism-7/.local/share/virtualenvs/apollo_django-njoxc1BQ/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 278, in __init__
    raise ValueError("\n".join(error.msg for error in errors))
ValueError: The field oauth2_provider.AccessToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but app 'oauth2' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.Grant.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but app 'oauth2' isn't installed.
The field oauth2_provider.RefreshToken.application was declared with a lazy reference to 'oauth2.companyfieldaddedapplication', but app 'oauth2' isn't installed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove you app from `apps` folder and keep it outside it. Then in your `INSTALLED_APPS` add following line.

```
installed_apps = [
   'oauth2.apps.Oauth2Config',
]
```

`Oauth2Config` is a `class` in `apps.py`

Your project structure should look like this

```
├── apollo_project
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.py.ren
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── apps
├── oauth2
     ├── admin.py
     ├── apps.py
     ├── __init__.py
     ├── models.py
     ├── tests.py
     ├── urls.py
     └── views.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `'oauth2'` to the installed_apps

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by dropping all the tables in my database and migrating. I'm not sure why it worked but it did. Hope I can help someone else out.